# How to break a line?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I have this line :

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT registeruser_id,registeruser_username, registeruser_email,registeruser_password FROM TestDB_RegisterUser where registeruser_email='" + email + "' and registeruser_password='" + pwd + "' and registeruser_rowstate<3 ";
```

And when I try to hit Enter on part of the string , I get a big bunch of red lines that indicates that what I did is considered as error .

How do I break it then ? thanks

Comment: If you put your exact title "How to break a C# line?" to the google - the first result will be an answer. Next time try doing this **BEFORE** asking it here. Thank you!

Comment: `... = "SELECT registeruser_id" + "..."` then hit enter after the plus sign

Comment: By the way, look up "parameters" and "sql injection". Do NOT just concatenate a sql string with user input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because a regular string literal can't include a line break in the source code. You can include one in a *verbatim string literal* however:

```
string sql = @"SELECT FOO
               FROM BAR
               WHERE X=Y";
```

Or break it with string concatenation:

```
string sql = "SELECT FOO " +
             "FROM BAR " +
             "WHERE X=Y";
```

More importantly, however, you're currently building your SQL in a [horribly insecure way](http://bobby-tables.com). *Never* include values directly in the SQL like this. Instead, use *parameterized SQL* and then specify values for the parameters:

```
string sql = "SELECT FOO FROM BAR WHERE X=@X";
using (var command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
{
    command.Parameters.Add("@X", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "...";
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        ...
    }
}
```